# How to get authenticated User in WebApi outside of controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, httprequest, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext

When in a controller I can just access the User property.  Outside of the controller I obviously cannot access the User property so after some reading I try HttpContext.Current.User, but HttpContext.Current is null.  This seems quite simple and I would rather not change my architecture so that I pass the user from the controller onto my other classes.